# Strange discontinuous initialisation behaviour in tf Keras sequential model (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot

I've been working on making a simple physics-informed neural network using a sequential model with dense layers in keras. Among other issues, I've noticed that when plotting some values after initialising that I get strange starting values. I believe this may be caused by an underlying issue messing with the rest of my code. Here are some relevant code snippets.

My MLP takes a position and time coordinate, and outputs a scalar value:

```
MLP = keras.Sequential([
    layers.InputLayer(input_shape = (1, 2)),
    layers.Dense(64, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=1), bias_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=1), activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(64, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=1), bias_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=1), activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(1),
])
```

and I've been plotting the initialised outputs at time t = 0 using matplotlib as

```
x_vals_plt = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 1000)
t_vals_plt = np.zeros(1000)

batch_mat = tf.reshape([x_vals_plt, t_vals_plt], [-1, 1, 2])
y_vals_plt = MLP(batch_mat)
y_vals_plt = np.reshape(y_vals_plt, [1000])

plt.plot(x_vals_plt, y_vals_plt)
plt.show()
```

As an example of the behaviour I'm noticing, I'm getting something like

[output from matplotlib code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVt1.png)

without the keras initialiser I got a very spike initialised value with flat lines everywhere other than a larger value towards the centre.

Any ideas on what could be causing this, or if it's just a repercussion of the relu activations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out -

Issue when generating the x and t values are that they are 1d arrays and thus reshaping didn't give the desired result, as an example:

x = [x1, x2, x3, ...]
t = [t1, t2, t3, ...]

then [x, t] = [x1, x2, x3, ..., t1, t2, t3, ...]

and reshape gave me [[x1, x2], [x3, x4], ..., [t1, t2], [t3, t4], ...]

instead of [[x1, t1], [x2, t2], ...]

This was fixed by making each array a 2d array, and concatenating them along the 1st axis using tf.concat.